# Unable to process a synchronous event asynchronously error in http

Tags: http, asynchronous, mule, mule-component

I have following flows in my mule config .

```
<flow name="SimpleTest" processingStrategy="asynchronous">
    <http:listener path="/orders/{id}" config-ref="myRequestConfig"
        allowedMethods="GET" />
    <set-payload value="SUCCESS" />
    <flow-ref name="subFlowTest" />
    <logger level="ERROR" message="value is : after subflow" />
</flow>
<sub-flow name="subFlowTest">
    <scripting:component doc:name="sleep">
        <scripting:script engine="groovy">
            <scripting:text>
        java.lang.Thread.sleep(5000);
    </scripting:text>
        </scripting:script>

    </scripting:component>
</sub-flow>
```

It gives Unable to process a synchronous event asynchronously error . i want to call the subflow asynchronously , so if my parent flow is asyncronous , the subflow will automatically becomes asyncronous , correct ? so why am i getting this error ?

Answer (score 2):

You can call your subflow asynchronously by using async message processor.

```
<async doc:name="Async">
    <flow-ref name="subFlowTest" doc:name="Call Sub Flow"/>
</async>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTTP endpoint makes a call to this flow through it automatically **synchronous**, so you have a conflict between your flow's strategy and its inbound endpoint. By definition, HTTP is synchronous.

Your problem lies on your understanding of HTTP.

Hope it helps.

/T

Answer (score 0):

`subflow` semantic is more like a macro expansion than a function call. You don't call a subflow, but use a subflow to extract message processors into a different xml structure for readability. In runtime it is the same than if you copy all the message processors of the subflow and put them inside the flow.
Why would you execute your `script` component asynchronously?